# requests method is not working on the URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from a website by using requests.get method. However, it returns SSL error but it worked in the past. Anyone can help me please?

The code like this:

```
import json
import requests

hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}    
url = "https://stockrow.com/api/companies/TEVA.json?ticker=TEVA"

response = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
info = json.loads(response.text)
info
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: no but I am using wifi with mobile network